# Git not importing new commits

Tags: git, intellij-idea, bitbucket

I am new to git and checked out a new project from my bitbucket repository. I used a fetch and a rebase (that's what I remember). Now there is a new commit but I can't see it on my machine.

`git log` does not show the latest commit,

`git status` says:

```
rebase in progress; onto f573eda
You are currently rebasing branch 'master' on 'f573eda'.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   HandyApp/app/App_Resources/Android/app.gradle
        modified:   HandyApp/app/pages/filmdetails/filmdetails-common.css
        modified:   HandyApp/app/pages/login/login.html
        modified:   HandyApp/app/services/configuration.service.ts
        modified:   HandyApp/package.json
        modified:   server/biff-code/src/main/java/de/hud/biff/api/BiffImageApi.java

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        .vs/
        HandyApp/app/App_Resources/Android/settings.gradle
        HandyApp/app/App_Resources/Android/settings.json

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

The new commit is shown in Bitbucket. I would like not to override my changes with a force pull, but to merge them. I install IntelliJ IDEA where I can also look up my git, also there the new commit is not shown. Do I need to update it manually?

---------------------------- Edit ------------------------------------

I did a `git stash` and got the following output:

```
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in HandyApp/package.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in HandyApp/app/App_Resources/Android/app.gradle.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in HandyApp/package.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
Saved working directory and index state WIP on (no branch): 6e6d982 rating and login
HEAD is now at 6e6d982 %message%
```

and a `git fetch` which took quite long and when I pressed `ctrl+c` to end it I got the following output:

```
remote: Counting objects: 23, done.
Unpacking objects: 100% (23/23), done.2)
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (22/22), done.
remote: Total 23 (delta 15), reused 0 (delta 0)
From %my_repo%
   6e6d982..e9cde9c  master     -> origin/master
```

------------------ Edit 2 ------------------------------

`git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all`  produces:

```
*   e98c6fe (refs/stash) WIP on (no branch): 6e6d982 rating and login
|\
| * 936ac06 index on (no branch): 6e6d982 rating and login
|/
| * e9cde9c (origin/master, origin/HEAD) Updated images and Login.css
|/
* 6e6d982 (HEAD) rating and login
* 5580145 rating and login
* b6230b4 Add FLOAT Type and Test
* f573eda Add FLOAT Type and add rating + mapping
* 774b370 Change to new Version of Export
| * 005443e (master) login and rating system
| * 16ab9e9 Login and Rating System
| * 92be0bb initial commit
| * 25406a5 (origin/feature-angular4) Adjustments Angular 4
|/
```

the `e9cde9c` is the latest commit

Comment: "staged in Bitbucket" makes no sense: "staged" files are changed in your local working copy that you have marked to be included in the next commit. Bitbucket is a *server* and there is no staging there.

Comment: does your workflow require a ff-only strategy, or are you allowed to merge?

Comment: And can you show us the first few lines of the output if you type `git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all` it will give me a better idea of the relationships between the commits we're looking at, You can obscure everything but the branch names and hashes and anonymize the branch names if you need to

Comment: I am allowed to do literally anything I want to do with the code - so I am allowed to merge

@LightBender I updated the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we'll need to get you out of the current rebase, so we'll run:

```
git rebase --abort
```

You've already stashed your changes, so we can skip that step, but if you had working copy changes, you'd stash them with:

```
git stash
```

Do another git fetch just to make sure you're completely up to date:

```
git fetch
```

Checkout the master branch:

```
git checkout master
```

And finally merge the changes from origin/master into your branch:

```
git merge origin/master
```

This should bring your repo up to date. You can then re-apply the stashed changes:

```
git stash pop
```

And you should be in good shape.

I recommend never making commits directly to master in order to avoid these kinds of issues, branching is so cheap and easy there really is no reason to risk breaking anything on your master branch. There are at least a dozen tried and true workflows out there depending on your team size, your project size, security requirements, etc. So look around and find one that will work for your team.

Comment: Thanks! Assuming that I am up-to-date and do not need to merge any more I would simply go for `git rebase --abort` and then commit it already? Or would I need another checkout?

Comment: `git checkout master` is only there to make sure you are on the correct branch, if you are already in the right place, no need to check out again.

Answer (score 2):

you can stash the changes you have in your local.

You need to revert the rebase first -

```
git rebase --abort
```

If you using separate branch for your project -

```
git stash
git checkout master or branch (where new project commit resides )
git pull
git checkout to branch (if you are using the same branch)
git merge branch name (where new project commit resides )
git stash apply
```

If same branch

```
git stash
git fetch
git pull branch name
git stash apply
```

Then check git log, you can see new commits

Comment: Thanks, so I always need to do a pull to even see new commits?

Comment: @Rüdiger This is a good answer from a clean repo, but it looks like you are in the middle of the rebase, so git will fight you if you try to do just about anything at this point. You'll need to abort the rebase first

Comment: @LightBender I posted an update, can you provide me an example of how to "fix" this? I am only having a few changes locally so I could also just override all my changes I guess